# iOS Adding to UITableView using array

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios, uitableview, sdk

Okay, I am trying to add a row to my tableview. I must be doing somthing wrong. I am adding to the array, is there a function that I am missing to refresh the UITableView using the new array?

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize toolbar;
@synthesize window;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",nil];
    theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [super viewDidLoad];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window addSubview:toolbar];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selectedTask = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedTask = selectedTask;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Your help is greatly appreciated as I have looked around the site and have seen something about pushing array to tableview but further research lead me into a wiled goose chase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have all of your [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods correctly defined, you probably just need to call reloadData on your UITableView. See the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference for details about the reloadData method.